# How to send email by simple email address using crm?

Tags: email, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2016, entityreference

I'm working with Dynamics CRM 2016, I want to send an Email from crm using an email address that the user insert (the email Id is taken from a field in `incident-Entity` and not from crm-user) according to examples online the option is to use entityreference from another entity that will hold and get the Email address, is there a way not to use Entityreference but instead get my email address from a simple field on incident form?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

**Update**:

> but instead get my email address from a simple field on incident form?

This is not possible in CRM UI. But possible using the code snippet from the [blog link in comment](http://worldofdynamics.blogspot.com/2012/04/dynamics-crm-2011-c-code-for-sending.html). You have to query the textbox content and put in recipient party address.

---

(These two lines are for sending email to activity party email Id from associated record non-email field from CRM UI, without any code or customization for this particular scenario)

Unfortunately you cannot achieve it.

Only way is associated record.

Comment: so If I understand correctly I must save my email address in any entity record and can only pass that email by entityreference to the crm sendmail function.

Comment: Yes, CRM is all about relationship management :) you can read this, it may be helpful. http://worldofdynamics.blogspot.com/2012/04/dynamics-crm-2011-c-code-for-sending.html?m=1

Answer (score 3):

You can use e-mail addresses that are not associated with e-mailaddress fields. It just requires a few steps.

In the UI navigate to ***Settings > System Settings > tab Email > header "Set Email form options"***.

Make sure setting "Allow messages with unresolved email recipients to be sent" is Yes.

Now you can use literal e-mail addresses like in this example:

```cs
var sender = new EntityCollection();
sender.Entities.Add(new Entity("activityparty")
{
    ["addressused"] = "me@home.test"
});

var recipients = new EntityCollection();
recipients.Entities.Add(new Entity("activityparty")
{
    ["addressused"] = "info@acme.test"
});

var eMail = new Entity("email")
{
    ["from"] = sender,
    ["to"] = recipients,
    ["subject"] = "Just a test",
    ["description"] = "Body of your e-mail"
};

organizationService.Create(eMail);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it `programmatically`! You can send an email to a person who is not a `Lead/Contact/Account`.. The CRM will send email but it will show un resolved referenced when you open it in CRM